# Can' t set directory for org-mode capture

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I was trying to use the capture as is explained in org-manual p. 85. This is the relevant part of my .emacs file.

```
  (setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "~/Notities/org-mode/Capture.org"))
    (define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
```

But I get this error.

> Symbol's value as variable is void: org-directory

I tried the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622603/org-mode-setup-problem-when-trying-to-use-capture#3622770), but it didn't work. The filepath is directed to an existing file. Why do I still get this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have the line `(require 'org)` before you set the location. This will ensure that the package `org` where `org-directory` is defined is loaded before it is used.

Also, if you are adding `concat`ing a path to `org-directory`, I think that the path you provide should be relative to `org-directory`, not an absolute path. In your case you might want to set:

```
(setq org-default-notes-file "~/Notities/org-mode/Capture.org")
```

instead. By default, I think `org-directory` is set to `~/org`, but if you don't want this as your default directory, you can change this as well. For example, in your case:

```
(setq org-directory "~/Notities/org-mode")
```

Combining these things, it should work to add:

```
(require 'org)
(setq org-directory "~/Notities/org-mode")
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/Capture.org"))
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
```

to your `.emacs` file.

Comment: How do I know where org-directory is?

Comment: @user72805 Try `C-h v org-directory` and it should show you what it is set to.